# Use function in another python file as Pyspark udf

Tags: python, function, apache-spark, pyspark, import

I have some python functions in a file named `features.py`

```
def printsth():
    print("123")
def get_email():
    #some code to get email 
    return email
```

I have another jupyter notebook script in the same directory named `main.ipynb`

I am trying to use the get_email function from `features.py` and use it as a udf on my PySpark dataframe in `main.ipynb`.

```
import features    
df = df.withColumn('email', (F.udf(lambda j:features.get_email(json.loads(j)), t.StringType()))('json'))
```

But I got the following error:

```
ImportError: ('No module named features', <function subimport at 0x7f5a5eed9a28>, ('features',))
```

But when I just tried to call the `printsth` function from `features.py` inside main.ipynb, it works just fine.

```
features.printsth()
123
```

Is there anything I need to do to make the `get_email function` to work in a PySpark dataframe?

Comment: Try this decorator @F.udf(StringType()) , i am able to import functrion from another module as udf and use it this way

Comment: @sangeethsasidharan yeah thats what I used. I just added my pyspark code in the question

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using the `%run features notebook` at the start of the notebook and then just call the functions directly
this should work